# Country ISO to "in France" (with preposition) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Given a country ISO I can know the country name using `Intl.DisplayNames` API with:

```js
const countryName = new Intl.DisplayNames([lang], { type: 'region' }).of(countryISO)
console.log(countryName) // France
```

However, I want to go one step further, and put the preposition in front of the country:

And depending on the country, it may be one or the other... But I don't know how this formula works... Is there any JavaScript API similar to DisplayNames that allows it?

NL:

- FR: **aux** Pays-Bas
- DE: **in die** Niederlande
- IT: **nei** Paesi Bassi

FR:

- FR: **en** France
- DE: **nach** Frankreich
- IT: **in** Francia

GB:

- FR: **au** Royaume-uni
- DE: **ins** Vereinigte Königreich
- IT: **nel** Regno Unito

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, what you're looking for is right on the border (no pun) between internationalization and translation. I suspect it may be just over the border into translation, though. :-) (In which case, there probably isn't a standard web API to do it.)

Comment: Yeah, no, I'm fairly certain there's no API for that. It would depend on context in the language, like "in die Niederlande", "für die Niederlande", "den Niederlanden" etc., depending on what you want to express. That's unreasonably complex for any standard API to offer.

Comment: Note that "in France" is ambiguous. In any case, you should solve it as you do for all the other texts:. with manual translation (and giving context for translator). Automatic translation of just text parts are never good.

Comment: The context is "Delivery in {{countryName}}". The only thing I know is the country ISO.

Comment: You'll either need to find something more neutral grammatically, like `Delivery country: {{countryName}}`, or you'll need to prepare a whole lot of translations, one per country and language.

Comment: Yes, if there is no formula to apply with a function or a JavaScript API to do it, there will be no other...! Thanks @deceze